# Can a JQuery Dialog open another Jquery Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-dialog

I want to open a partial view as a JQuery dialog that when I click a link to open another Jquery dialog over the one that is already open.

Can I do that? If it is possible, how can I achieve that?

Edit 1:

First view

```
@model AuctionWebProject.Areas.Admin.Models.CategoryModel  
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Category";  
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";  
}  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>EditCategory</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function ShowXsdEditor() {  
            $("#xsdEditor").dialog("open");  
        }  
    </script>  
    @using (Html.BeginForm())  
    {  
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)  
        <fieldset>  
            <legend>CategoryModel</legend>  
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)  
            <div class="editor-label">  
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)  
            </div>  
            <div class="editor-field">  
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)  
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)  
            </div>  
            <div class="editor-label">  
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)  
            </div>  
            <div class="editor-field">  
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)  
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)  
            </div>  
            <div class="editor-label">  
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Xsd)  
            </div>  
            <div class="editor-field">  
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Xsd, new { disabled = "disabled" })  
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Xsd)  
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ShowXsdEditor();">Xsd Editor</a>  
            </div>  
            <p>  
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />  
            </p>  
        </fieldset>  
    }  
    <div>  
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")  
    </div>  
    @Html.Partial("XsdEditor", Model)  
</body>  
</html>
```

Second view

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<div id="xsdEditor" style="display: none;">  
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ShowDialog();">Add new element</a>  
     <div id="elementList">  
     </div>  
</div>  
@Html.Partial("AddXSElement", new AuctionWebProject.Areas.Admin.Models.XSElementModel())  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $("#xsdEditor").dialog({  
            autoOpen: false, width: 400, height: 330, modal: true, title:'XSD Editor'  
        });  
    });  

    function ShowDialog() {  
        debugger;  
        $("#addXSElement").dialog("open");  
    }  
</script>
```

I use JQuery v 1.6.2 and Jquery Ui 1.8.12

Comment: Did you try it before asking?  You just call `$('#otherDialog').dialog('open')`, and the new dialog will appear over the first one.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MZAtp/.  Show us your code, and we can try to help.

Comment: Please give us only HTML and JS without the server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it seems that the JQuery function that was in the document ready didn't work as it should.
After reordering the dialogs java script, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/sZUaK/1/) I have created, it will show up with no problem.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, in which case this should be moved to another question.